# How to return null when accessing a moq object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am using Moq library for unit testing. Now what i want is that when I access my object for the first time it should return null, and when i access this on second time it should return something else.

here is my code

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyClass>();
mock.Setup(?????);
mock.Setup(?????);

var actual = target.Method(mock.object);
```

in my method i am first checking that whether mock object is null or not, if it is null then do initialize it and then do some calls on it.

```
bool Method(IMyClass myObj)
{
    if (myObj != null)
        return true;
    else
    {
        myObj = new MyClass();
        bool result = myObj.SomeFunctionReturningBool();
        return result;
    }
}
```

what to do setup for mock object,

Also i need to know how to mock this line

```
bool result = myObj.SomeFunctionReturningBool();
```

Comment: this is not related with mocking, just call Method in your class passing null to realize your unit test

Comment: I don't quite get it. The idea of creating mock is to not have null as IMayClass. If you want null then just invoke `target.Method(null)`. To the second question: you just cannot. You create instance of MyClass and then invoke method on it so it cannot be mocked.

Comment: method else condition will run only if myObj is null, and in else i have to make a call to SomeFunctionReturningBool, and if send null then i cannot mock this function,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to run two tests with one test method - maybe it would be better to split the tests into two?

You also want to initialise a new object if the method is passed null. To test this, I suggest creating a factory object responsible for creating instances of `MyClass`. The new code would look like:

```
interface IMyClassFactory
{
    IMyClass CreateMyClass();
}

bool Method(IMyClass myObj, IMyClassFactory myClassFactory)
{
    if (myObj != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    myObj = myClassFactory.CreateMyClass();
    return myObj.SomeFunctionReturningBool();
}
```

Then the tests would look like:

```
[Test]
public void Method_ShouldReturnTrueIfNotPassedNull()
{
    Assert.That(target.Method(new MyClass()), Is.True);
}

[Test]
public void Method_ShouldCreateObjectAndReturnResultOfSomeFunctionIfPassedNull()
{
    // Arrange
    bool expectedResult = false;

    var mockMyClass = new Mock<IMyClass>();
    mockMyClass.Setup(x => x.SomeFunctionReturningBool()).Returns(expectedResult);

    var mockMyFactory = new Mock<IMyClassFactory>();
    mockMyFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateMyClass()).Returns(mockMyClass.Object);

    // Act
    var result = target.Method(null, mockMyFactory.Object);

    // Assert
    mockMyClass.Verify(x => x.SomeFunctionReturningBool(), Times.Once());
    mockMyFactory.Verify(x => x.CreateMyClass(), Times.Once());
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));
}
```

Here the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) has been used to pass in an object which can create objects of `IMyClass` type, and then the factory itself has been mocked.

If you do not want to change your method's signature, then create the factory in the class's constructor, and make it accessible via a public property of the class. It can then be overwritten in the test by the mock factory. This is called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: i have removed new MyClass() line, i cannot use your solution because function comes to else only if object is null, everytime i pass a mock object to it only if condition will run,

Answer (score 2):

Moq - Return null - This working example simply illustrates how to return null using Moq. While the line of code is required is the commented line below, a full working example is provided below.

```
// _mockShopService.Setup(x => x.GetProduct(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => null);

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IShopService
{
    Product GetProduct(string productId);
}

public class ShopService : IShopService
{
    public Product GetProduct(string productId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productId))
        {
            return new Product();
        }

        return new Product { Id = "8160807887984", Name = "How to return null in Moq" };
    }
}

public class Shop
{
    private static IShopService _shopService;

    public Shop(IShopService shopService)
    {
        _shopService = shopService;
    }

    public Product GetProduct(string productId)
    {
        Product product = _shopService.GetProduct(productId);

        return product;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ShopTests
{
    Mock<IShopService> _mockShopService;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mockShopService = new Mock<IShopService>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShopService_GetProduct_Returns_null()
    {
        //Arrange
        Shop shop = new Shop(_mockShopService.Object);

        //This is how we return null --- all other code above is to bring this line of code home
        _mockShopService.Setup(x => x.GetProduct(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => null);

        //Act
        var actual = shop.GetProduct(It.IsAny<string>());

        //Assert

        Assert.IsNull(actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To mock a result value you can do simply:

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.SomeFunctionReturningBool()).Returns(true); // or false :)
```

for the other question, just pass null in the unit test instead of passing `mock.object` and your unit test cover that too. So you basically create two unit test one with:

```
var actual = target.Method(mock.object);
```

and the other one with:

```
var actual = target.Method(null);
```

Comment: the else condition of Method() runs when null is passed to it, but if i pass null to it then Obj.SomeFunctionReturningBool cannot be mocked,

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestFixture with parameter. this test will run two times and different type value.

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Project.Tests
{
    [TestFixture(1)] 
    [TestFixture(2)]
    public class MyTest
    {
        private int _intType;

         public MyTest(int type)
         {
             _intType = type;
         }

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            if (_intType==1)
            {
                //Mock Return false
            }
            else
            {
                //Mock Return Value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your SUT is tight-coupled with `MyClass` implementation. You can't mock objects which are instantiated with `new` keyword inside your SUT. Thus you cannot test your SUT in isolation, and *your test is **not unit test** anymore*. When implementation of `MyClass.SomeFunctionReturningBool` will change (it will return `true` instead of `false`), tests of your SUT will fail. This shouldn't happen. Thus, delegate creation to some dependency (factory) and inject that dependency to your SUT:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldReturnTrueWhenMyClassIsNotNull()
{
    Mock<IMyClassFactory> factory = new Mock<IMyClassFactory>();
    Mock<IMyClass> myClass = new Mock<IMyClass>();
    var foo = new Foo(factory.Object);
    Assert.True(foo.Method(myClass.Object));
}

[Test]
public void ShouldCreateNewMyClassAndReturnSomeFunctionValue()
{
    bool expected = true;
    Mock<IMyClass> myClass = new Mock<IMyClass>();
    myClass.Setup(mc => mc.SomeFunctionReturningBool()).Returns(expected);
    Mock<IMyClassFactory> factory = new Mock<IMyClassFactory>();
    factory.Setup(f => f.CreateMyClass()).Returns(myClass.Object);

    var foo = new Foo(factory.Object);

    Assert.That(foo.Method(null), Is.EqualTo(expected));
    factory.VerifyAll();
    myClass.VerifyAll();
}
```

BTW assignment new value to method parameter does not affect reference which you passed to method.

Implementation:

```
public class Foo
{
    private IMyClassFactory _factory;

    public Foo(IMyClassFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public bool Method(IMyClass myObj)
    {
        if (myObj != null)
            return true;       

        return _factory.CreateMyClass().SomeFunctionReturningBool();
    }
}
```