# Xunit - Moq always returns a null value even after setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

Hi I am having an issue with my moq when I try to return data, I saw this [questtion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502543/how-to-return-null-when-accessing-a-moq-object) with a solution but it doesn't work on my side.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong

1. Here is my respository

   ```
    private readonly IRepository<SomeClass<MyObject>> repository;
    public MyObjectRepository(IRepositoryFactory factory)
    {
        repository = factory.RepositoryOf<SomeClass<MyObject>>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyObject>> GetAllAsync(string SomeParameter)
    {
        var result = await repository.GetAsync(x => x.OtherParameter == $"{SomeParameter}.{nameof(MyObject)}s", default);
        var reportDataItem = result.FirstOrDefault();

        if (reportDataItem == null)
            return null;

        return reportDataItem.Collection;
    }
   ```
2. Here is my test
   var data = await MockDBHelper.GetAirportsAsync(someParameter, true);

   ```
        mockIRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(null, default)).ReturnsAsync(data);

        mockFactory.Setup(x => x.RepositoryOf<SomeClass<MyObject>>()).Returns(mockIRepository.Object);

        _repo = new MyObjectRepository(mockFactory.Object);

        var result = await _repo.GetAllAsync(AirlineCd);

        mockRepository.Verify(x => x.GetAsync(null,default), Times.Once());
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
mockIRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(null, default)).ReturnsAsync(data);
```

will only return `data` when the values of `null` and the `default` value are passed as the two parameters. Since you are passing a function as the first parameter it is not null, therefore not matching the setup. Instead you could tell mock to "Match anything" for the function.

```
mockIRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<Func<PARAMETER_TYPE, RETURN_TYPE>>(), default)).ReturnsAsync(data);
```

You will need to replace `PARAMETER_TYPE` and `RETURN_TYPE` with the appropriate types used in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I just need to re-structure my code because it fails if I have to parameters on my GetAsync and passes when I'm only passing 1 parameter. So I created a new method with only 1 parameter(Func) and it's working. Much appreciated.